# Prove that the function is bijective

Tags: calculus, functions

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by, $$f(x)={x+\arctan(x)}.$$ 
Prove that this function is bijective.

Here's my attempt:-
Since $x$ and $\arctan(x)$ are continuous, $f(x)={x+\arctan(x)}$ is also continuous. And further, $$ f'(x) = 1+ \frac1{1+x^2}\gt 0 \quad\forall x \in\mathbb{R}$$

Therefore the function is strictly increasing and hence, is strictly monotonic. Therefore this function is bijective. Would this be correct? Can you show me a better way (that doesn't involve derivative) of proving this? Thank you!

Comment: Well...$e^x$ is strictly increasing but it is not a bijection.  Your argument is good, but incomplete,

Comment: You are implicitly using the Intermediate Value Theorem in your argument.  If you want to show the function reaches every value in the interval $[-M, M]$, you first need to show that it reaches $M$ and $-M$.

Comment: Your argument applies without change to the function $\arctan(x)$. But $\arctan(x)$ isn't bijective! So you must have gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have shown that $f$ is injective.

It remains to show that $f$ is surjective: to this end let $y_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $ x\to \infty$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $ x\to -\infty$, there are $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $a<b, f(b)> y_0$ and $f(a) <y_0$.

The intermediate value theorem shows now that $f(x_0)=y_0$ for some $x_0 \in [a,b].$

Comment: Is $x sinx$ bijective over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: No, $x\sin x$ has a lot of zeros.

Answer (score 3):

A strictly monotonic function need not be surjective. In this case $-\pi /2 <\arctan x< \pi /2$ so $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. From this it follows that the range (which is necessarily an interval by IVP) is the whole real line.

Comment: Strict monotonicity is a necessary condition for $f(x)$ to be bijective, but not sufficient?

Comment: Over which domain is $xsinx$ bijective? I don't think it is bijective over $\mathbb{R}$ ,as it has zeroes in $\mathbb{R}$ for multiple $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Samurai You're right, and Kavi is wrong. Bijective, continuous functions must be monotonic as bijective must be one-to-one, so the function cannot attain any particular value more than once.

Comment: Thank you @Shufflepants :-))

Comment: But of course, it is possible to have a discontinuous function that is not monotonic but bijective. Though, it must be monotonic on every interval on which it is continuous.

Comment: Define $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$  by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x ,& \text{if $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$}\\ 1-x, & \text{if $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q^c}$}\end{cases}$$ would this do as an example?

Comment: @Shufflepants ,Is this function bijective? It's clearly not continuous and monotonic.

Comment: @XaYb I believe so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86340/discussion-between-xa-yb-and-shufflepants).